# How do I specify the platform for MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to use MSBuild to build a solution with a specified target platform (I need both binaries, x86 and x64). This is how I tried it:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5>MsBuild SolutionPath\Solution.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x86"
```

However the build always fails if the platform is different from "Any CPU". What am I doing wrong?

This is the while output MSBuild prints:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5>MsBuild
> SolutionPath\Solution.sln /t:Rebuild
> /p:Configuration=Release
> /p:Platform="x86" Microsoft (R) Build
> Engine Version 3.5.30729.1 [Microsoft
> .NET Framework, Version
> 2.0.50727.3082] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights
> reserved.
>
> Build started 1.7.2010 8:28:10.
> Project "SolutionPath\Solution.sln" on
> node 0 (Rebuild targe t(s)).
> SolutionPath\Solution.sln : error
> MSB4126: The specified sol ution
> configuration "Release|x86" is
> invalid. Please specify a valid
> solution c onfiguration using the
> Configuration and Platform properties
> (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln
> /p:Configuration=Debug
> /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those
> prope rties blank to use the default
> solution configuration. Done Building
> Project "SolutionPath\Solution.sln"
> (Rebuild t arget(s)) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "SolutionPath\Solution.sln" (Rebuild
> target) (1) ->
> (ValidateSolutionConfiguration target)
> ->   SolutionPath\Solution.sln : error MSB4126: The specified s olution
> configuration "Release|x86" is
> invalid. Please specify a valid
> solution  configuration using the
> Configuration and Platform properties
> (e.g. MSBuild.ex e Solution.sln
> /p:Configuration=Debug
> /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those
> pro perties blank to use the default
> solution configuration.
>
> ```
> 0 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.03

If I try to build it for x86/x64 with devenv it works perfectly, however I am trying to set up a build server without installing all the necessary versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: How does it fail?  Maybe some projects don't support x86 platform?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need /p:Platform="Win32"?

Comment: For future readers getting here and wondering how to get the 2017 version of MSBuild installed on a machine without installing Visual Studio, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42696948/1364007).

Comment: @AndrewWyatt - afaik - C++ uses `Win32` whilst moden .NET uses `x86`

Comment: @ElliotWoods - thanks for the clarification re: Win32/x86 - my view would only have been from C++ point of view.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If you want to build your solution for **x86** and **x64**, your solution must be configured for both platforms. Actually you just have an **Any CPU** configuration.

### How to check the available configuration for a project

To check the available configuration for a given project, open the project file (`*.csproj` for example) and look for a `PropertyGroup` with the right `Condition`.

If you want to build in `Release` mode for `x86`, you must have something like this in your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

### How to create and edit the configuration in Visual Studio

[image: Configuration Manager panel]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Cc563937.11a492fe-e240-4cdd-9b53-b6aae7224b09(en-us,office.12).jpg))</sub>

[image: New solution platform button]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/habibh/WindowsLiveWriter/9d46e66e51d6_13278/image_15.png))</sub>

[image: New solution platform panel]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/habibh/WindowsLiveWriter/9d46e66e51d6_13278/image_18.png))</sub>

[How to create and edit the configuration](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984) (on MSDN)

Comment: What's the difference in using x86 or x64?

Comment: x86 builds 32 bits dll/executable and x64 builds 64 bits dlls/executable.

Comment: @Julien can/should i use .targets file for setting up shared configurations?

Comment: Some projects use `Win32` instead of `x86` for instance, `CMake` generated ones do (`libssh2` uses `CMake`).

Answer (score 298):

In MSBuild or Teamcity use command line

```
MSBuild yourproject.sln /property:Configuration=Release /property:Platform=x64
```

or use shorter form:

```
MSBuild yourproject.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```

Note that a multiword argument on the command line is wrapped with double quotes. So `Platform="Any CPU"` or `Platform="Mixed Platforms"` for those who need it.

However you need to set up platform in your project anyway, see the answer by Julien Hoarau.

Comment: didn't realize the sub-setting for /property to identify both the configuration and platform.  Thanks

Comment: Beware that MSBuild does not consider Visual Studio "Solution configurations", but instead sets properties before executing the xxproj  for each project of the solution. The platform and configuration will be the same for each project of the solution, no matter what mix of project configurations you selected in Visual Studio.

Comment: Or possibly shorter: /p:Configuration=Release;AnyOtherParameter=Abc123;Platform=x86

Answer (score 14):

If you're trying to do this from the command line, you may be encountering an issue where a machine-wide environment variable 'Platform' is being set for you and working against you. I can reproduce this if I use the VS2012 Command window instead of a regular windows Command window.

At the command prompt type:

> set platform

In a VS2012 Command window, I have a value of 'X64' preset. That seems to interfere with whatever is in my solution file.

In a regular Command window, the 'set' command results in a "variable not defined" message...which is good.

If the result of your 'set' command above returns no environment variable value, you should be good to go.

Comment: This is of course how a VS2012 x64 command window is differentiated from a VS2012 x86 command window. IOW, by design, not "interference"

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully this helps someone out there.

For platform I was specifying `"Any CPU"`, changed it to `"AnyCPU"` and that fixed the problem.

```
msbuild C:\Users\Project\Project.publishproj /p:Platform="AnyCPU"  /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=local /p:Configuration=Debug
```

If you look at your .csproj file you'll see the correct platform name to use.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2017 and 2019... with the [modern core library SDK project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2019), the platform can be changed during the build process. Here's an example to change to the `anycpu` platform, just before the built-in `CoreCompile` task runs:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" >

  <Target Name="SwitchToAnyCpu" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" >
    <Message Text="Current Platform=$(Platform)" />
    <Message Text="Current PlatformTarget=$(PlatformName)" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Platform>anycpu</Platform>
      <PlatformTarget>anycpu</PlatformTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="New Platform=$(Platform)" />
    <Message Text="New PlatformTarget=$(PlatformTarget)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

In my case, I'm building an FPGA with `BeforeTargets` and `AfterTargets` tasks, but compiling a C# app in the main `CoreCompile`. (partly as I may want some sort of command-line app, and partly because I could not figure out how to omit or override `CoreCompile`)

To build for multiple, concurrent binaries such as x86 and x64: either a separate, manual build task would be needed or two separate project files with the respective `<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>` and `<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>` settings in the example, above.

Answer (score 0):

When you define different build configurations in your visual studio solution for your projects using a tool like [ConfigurationTransform](https://github.com/golavr/ConfigurationTransform), you may want your Teamcity build, to build you a specified build configuration. You may have build configurations e.g., Debug, Release, Dev, UAT, Prod etc defined. This means, you will have MSBuild Configuration transformation setup for the different configurations. These different configurations are usually used when you have different configurations, e.g. different database connection strings, for the different environment. This is very common because you would have a different database for your production environment from your playground development environment.

They say a picture is worth a thousand words, please see the image below how you would specify multiple build configurations in Teamcity.

In the commandline input text box, specify as below

`/p:OutputPath=Publish;Configuration=Dev`

Here, I have specified two commandline build configurations/arguments `OutputPath` and build `Configuration` with values `Publish` and `Dev` respectively, but it could have been, `UAT` or `Prod` configuration. If you want more, simply separate them by semi-colon,`;`

[image: Teamcity MSBuild Commandline build configuration screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There is an odd case I got in VS2017, about **the space between ‘Any’ and 'CPU'.**
this is **not about using command prompt**.

If you have a **build project file**, which could **call other solution files**. You can try to add the space between Any and CPU, like this (the Platform property value):

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionToBuild2)" Properties ="Configuration=$(ProjectConfiguration);Platform=Any CPU;Rerun=$(MsBuildReRun);" />
```

Before I fix this build issue, it is like this (ProjectPlatform is a global variable, was set to 'AnyCPU'):

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionToBuild1)" Properties ="Configuration=$(ProjectConfiguration);Platform=$(ProjectPlatform);Rerun=$(MsBuildReRun);" />
```

Also, we have a lot projects being called using $ (ProjectPlatform), which is 'AnyCPU' and work fine. If we open proj file, we can see lines liket this and it make sense.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
```

So my conclusion is,
'AnyCPU' works for calling project files, but not for calling solution files,
for calling solution files, using 'Any CPU' (add the space.)

For now, I am not sure if it is a bug of VS project file or MSBuild.
I am using VS2017 with VS2017 build tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019, version 16.8.4, you can just add

```
<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
```