# Setting up a .NET Core project to build for multiple operating systems in VS Code?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I have a .NET Core project on a drive that's shared between my Windows and Linux installations, and I wanted to know if it was possible to set up my VS Code project so that it would put each build (the Windows and Linux builds, in this case) in its own subfolder in the build folder. I've tried googling it, but all I get are results for having multiple projects in the same solution -- not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: look @ msbuild https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155492/how-do-i-specify-the-platform-for-msbuild#29311331

Comment: You’d better use a script for that, like https://github.com/lextm/restructuredtext-antlr/blob/v1.0.1/dist.server.ps1