# How to set 'Platform' when running MSBuild on .NET

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity, unreal-engine4

I'm attempting to build an Unreal project on TeamCity. I have a build step failing at `.NET` running `msbuild` (`cross-platform MSBuild`). The configuration is `Development Editor`. Error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(22,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project '<project-file>.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='arm64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
```

When building locally the Platform is `Win64` (I think). But I dont know how to set this when building through TeamCity?

Comment: Is the agent you're building it on also Windows or is it Linux based? Not too familiar with `msbuild` exactly but I'd start by trying to make your local build similar to how it'd be built in TeamCity. This guide may also be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2022

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155492/how-do-i-specify-the-platform-for-msbuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be set at the `.NET` build step in Teamcity. There is a field for `Command Line Parameters` in which you can include

```
/p:Platform="<platform>"
```