# How to specify the platform in devenv build CruiseControl.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, devenv

When building with msbuild we can give the platform as below

```
<msbuild>
<buildArgs>Platform=x86</buildArgs>
</msbuild>
```

Do you know how to speficify the platform if we are using devenv?

```
<devenv>
???
</devenv>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
<devenv>
    <configuration>Configuration|Platform</configuration>
</devenv>
```

for example:

```
<devenv>
    <configuration>Debug|Win32</configuration>
</devenv>
```

Comment: Can you give an example? <configuration>Release|x86</configuration>?